# Comment présenter deux personnes qui se connaissent pas

Tags: politesse, société

D'après [cet article](http://www.labelleecole.fr/blog/1729-presenter-invites-regles-politesse-savoir-vivre-soiree/),

> On présente toujours la personne la plus jeune à la plus âgée et l’inférieure à la supérieure (professionnellement par exemple).
>
> Par contre, on présentera toujours (ou presque) un homme à une femme, et non l’inverse afin d’éviter de laisser le quiproquo s’installer.
>
> **Cette dernière règle peut être contredite si l’homme occupe une position bien supérieure**[...]

En France, comment fait-on dans cette dernière situation en parlant d'un cas professionnellement ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about the French language, but about culture and society.

Comment: Ikr, and sorry for the off-topic. But I found our community usually gives accurated answers, and I don't know where/anybody to ask it. I'm currently living in an orient country.

Comment: Yes - I am not sure if there is a stackexchange that would be more appropriate for this question. For the question itself, I think we would just say "Je vous présente so-and-so", without making too big a deal out of it, especially in the business world.

Comment: La réponse (qui n'a pas sa place sur French Language) peut se lire ici : http://fr.wikihow.com/faire-les-pr%C3%A9sentations (partie 3 et +)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no direct link to French language.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a plusieurs types de présentations:

- un nouvel embauché/stagiaire Tom arrive. Son manager Bob lui fait faire le tour des bureaux et le présente de cette manière à chaque personne, dont John.

> *Bob parle à John* > Hey John, je te présente Tom. Il rejoint l'équipe pour travailler sur telle tâche.
>   *Bob parle à Tom*  > John travaille sur telle partie du produit.
>   *Tom et John se serrent la main et échangent deux trois mots comme "Bienvenue"*

- une réunion a lieu entre deux équipes (client/fournisseur ou deux équipes du même employeur). Je pense à deux solutions :

  1. le responsable de la réunion fait les présentations (plus plausible quand tout le monde est de la même maison). Les chefs sont présentés d'abord puis c'est au tour des autres.
  2. un tour de table est organisé ou chacun se présente de manière succinte:

     > Je m'appelle Bob, je travaille dans cette équipe depuis 2 ans et demi, et suis plus particulièrement en charge de telle activité.